# Why is python printing a whole list when I'm asking it to iterate through the list?

Tags: python, random, iteration

What about this code is causing it to print a whole list for i rather than each item in the list?

```
population = []
total = 0
for i in range(1, 31):
    population.append(i)
while total < 101:
    sample = [random.sample(population, 5)]
    for i in sample:
        print(i)
        print(sample.count(i))
    total += 1
```

It is printing the list of five numbers randomly sampled from the 30 generated in the "population" list and looks like this:

```
[12, 3, 14, 16, 9]
1
```

BUT if I just do the exact same code with a non randomly-generated "sample" list, it prints the numbers as iterated on separate lines:

```
sample = [12, 3, 14, 16, 9]
    for i in sample:
        print(i)
        print(sample.count(i))
```

Printed result:

```
12
1
3
1
14
1
16
1
9
1
```

What's the difference? Thank you!

Comment: `random.sample()` already returns a list. By putting it inside `[` and `]` you are creating a list of lists.

Comment: OH MY GOSH THANK YOU

Comment: The above reason is also why `sample.count(i)` returns 1 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing `sample = [random.sample(population, 5)]`
But `random.sample` already returns an array, so you're wrapping an array inside an array.
You probably meant to do:

```
sample = random.sample(population, 5)
```